# I can get the first cell value by using index in VBA but not later cell values in that range

Tags: excel, vba, range

If I set a range variable like this in VBA,

```
Dim xRg As Range
Set xRg = Range("D1:J13")
```

then I am getting the value in D1 cell by `msgbox(xRg(1))`,but following the logic I am getting blank if I do `msgbox(xRg(2))` or `msgbox(xRg(3))`

why does it behave like that ??I can get the values out I just do not understand this behaviour

Comment: As a hint, what does `MsgBox xRg(2).Address` return?

Comment: It returns an empty string,but returns the value in D1  when I am doing xRg(1)

Comment: Did you actually add in the `.Address` as I mentioned?

Comment: Sorry no I did not ,Now using address it returns $E$2 and it is blank,so I understand it,thank you

Comment: I do understand now,basically it goes by columns when I thought it goes by rows,thanks BigBen

Comment: If you want to access cells adjacent to a range, you can use `.Offset(<row offset>, <column offset>)`.